# Does $R \langle x_1, \cdots, x_n\rangle $ have the IBN property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it known, for a general nontrivial ring $R$, whether the finitely generated free algebra $R \langle x_1, \cdots, x_n\rangle  $ has the IBN property? What if $R$ is more restricted? Thanks.

Comment: If there is a homomorphism $A \to B$ where $B$ has IBN, then $A$ has IBN (Lam, Lectures on Modules and Rings, p4 (1.5)). So at the very least it's true if $R$ itself has IBN.